# Valid Signing identity Not Found in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Actually i developed an app using my own developer certificates and provisioning  profile.
Now  i need to publish it on my client developer account and my client sent his distribution certificate along with provisioning .And I have installed the certificate and then i drag the provisioning profile to xcode, and i have got error message like "Valid  signing identity not found"

Please assits me.

Comment: set your code signing in your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code sign in project settings.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need p12 file from your client to use its developer certificate and provisioning profile.When your client provide you that p12 file than double click that file and its run perfectly.

And for geting p12 file ,select the cert, and open the arrow to also select the private key and export them together as a .p12 file from Keychain Access.

Answer (score 0):

You need the private keys that were used to sign the certificate. If you don't have them

anymore you can generate a new signing request.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this issue.

The first one is, to export your developer certificate including the associated key from your keychain and importing it on your client machine.

The other way would be (If your client machine would use another apple dev account) to go through those steps listed here [Apple Certification & Provisioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/CodeSigning/CodeSigning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH7-SW1/)

I would recommend to delete the old certificates from xcode, sometimes xcode might lag otherwise